# Find the orthogonal projection $p$ of the vector $v$ on the line $\{ta+b, -\infty < t < \infty\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, projection-matrices

This is a practice problem in a 400-level linear algebra course. This is supposed to be review of 200-level material. For some reason, I'm having a mental block trying to understand the solution given.

> Problem: Let $\bar{a}=\big[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{smallmatrix}\big]$, $\bar{b}=\big[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix}\big]$, and $\bar{v}=\big[\begin{smallmatrix}0 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix}\big]$. Find the orthogonal projection $\bar{p}$ of the vector $\bar{v}$ on the line $\{t \bar{a}+\bar{b}, -\infty < t < \infty \}$.
>
> Solution: Let $\bar{p} = t\bar{a}+\bar{b}$, then $0=\bar{a}^T(\bar{v}-\bar{p})$, and $t=-\frac{1}{2}$. Finally $\bar{p}=\big[\begin{smallmatrix} 1/2 \\ -1/2 \end{smallmatrix}\big]$.

The part I don't understand is that $\bar{v}=\big[\begin{smallmatrix}0 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix}\big]$. I keep wanting to apply the formula:
$$ \text{proj}_\bar{p}\bar{v}=\frac{\bar{v}\cdot\bar{p}}{\bar{p}\cdot\bar{p}}\bar{p}$$ But $\bar{v}$ just ends up cancelling everything out. Is there another formula I'm missing?

If someone can explain the reasoning behind this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I think the question actually means for $p$ to be the point on the line $ta + b$ that is closest to $v$.

Comment: That actually clears it right up for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$v$ is the vector (the origin in this case) you are projecting on to the line $t \mapsto ta+b$. The line does **not** pass through the origin.

Solve $\min_t {1 \over 2} \|ta+b-v\|^2 $. Differentiating and finding where the derivative
is zero gives
$a^T (ta+b-v) = 0$ or $t = {a^T(v-b) \over \|a\|^2}$, computing gives $t=-{1 \over 2}$ and so the closest point is $ta+b = \binom{{1 \over 2}}{-{1 \over 2}}$.